# spring security with javaconfig automatically redirected to login.htm?logout

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

After converting Spring Security Xml configuration into javaconfig, home page is automatcally redirected to /login.htm?logout . Home page is not coming. Also, login attempt is failing.

working Xml configuration:

```
<http pattern="/resources" security="none" />

<!-- HTTP security configurations -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/personal/myPhotos.htm"
        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_FAMILY', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/personal/familyPhotos.htm"
        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_FAMILY', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        login-page="/login.htm" authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?login_error=t" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/" />

    <remember-me key="myAppKey" token-validity-seconds="864000" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />

</http>

<beans:bean id="encoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

non-working javaconfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder registry)
        throws Exception {
    registry.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin.htm")
            .hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/personal/myPhotos.htm")
            .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_FAMILY", "ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/personal/familyPhotos.htm")
            .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_FAMILY", "ROLE_ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.htm")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .failureUrl("/login.htm?login_error=t")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/")
        .and()
            .rememberMe().key("myAppKey").tokenValiditySeconds(864000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE-EDIT:

Based on the comment provided i can see the problem would be with your following piece of code:

```
.and()
    .logout().logoutUrl("/")
```

Based on that code setup it means every time you go to your homepage/index page it will return
http:///login?logout as per your problem.

I'm going to assume that you want to redirect to homepage/index page so therefore i present you this fix:

```
.and()
    .logout()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
```

If this doesn't work please advise and i'll assist you further, otherwise accepting my answer will be thank you enough :).

Comment: First, I have used hasAuthority() instead of hasRole() because I do not want to automatically prefix with "ROLE_". Secondly, there are no Controllers under /login mapping in my application. However, I am adding view controller like this: registry.addViewController("/login.htm").setViewName("login");

Comment: yes that solved the issue. However, after correcting it, I am able to navigate to any page and no security is applied.  And on removing .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() line, all pages are redirecting to login.htm. I want some of my pages, do not require any security access.

Comment: Remember sequence is the key here. Move your .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() to the bottom of the list of your antMatchers. That is between .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_FAMILY", "ROLE_ADMIN") and .anyRequest().authenticated().

Comment: After correcting the sequence, I found one more issue. I am getting UserNotFoundException on login. On debugging, I figure out username is passed blank in loadUserByUsername method of CustomUserDetailsService class.

Comment: Ok after setting loginForm().usernameParameter("j_username").passwordParameter("j_password") it worked! thanks